# Problem in Listview Custom adapter class

Tags: android

I am explaining my issue straightaway. Please refer the following code snippet.

```
@Override
public View getView(int index, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Comments comment = comments.get(index);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.comment_row, null);
    }

    TextView tvAuthor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentAuthor);
    System.out.println("tvAuthor"+tvAuthor);
    tvAuthor.setText(comment.getAuthor());
    convertView.setTag(comment);
    return convertView;
}
```

I get null for tvAuthor . As a result, in the immediate next line where I try to setText, I get null pointer exception.

I have declared commentAuthor in the xml correctly. I cannot trace, from where this error pops up. Experts, kindly help.

ny help in this regard is well appreciated.

Look forward,
Regards,
Rony

Comment: Looks like it can't find commentAuthor inside of convertView you should post your comment_row xml. Also you can just use the static View.inflate()  its a little shortcut.

Comment: @user264953: "I have declared commentAuthor in the xml correctly." -- please post the layout XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that View.findViewById() is called after View.onCreate() since this is when XML is parsed.

Preferably you'd put .findViewById() inside .onCreate() and save the result in a field for use elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the line:

```
 System.out.println("tvAuthor"+tvAuthor);
```

As **you have declared tvAuthor as TextView**, this variable refers to the textview, not its value, so while displaying value from the textview to the console, you needs to write:

```
if(! tvAuthor.getText.toString.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{
    System.out.println("tvAuthor"+ tvAuthor.getText.toString());
}
```

so that it will take a value from the tvAuthor TextView and then display on the console.

Comment: He would still get null for tvAuthor.